# Run batch file after each build in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a number of projects that I work on simultaneously.

Every time I build and run one of them, the apk is located as usual in the bin folder.

If I want to copy this apk to some other folder outside the project, I have to do it manually.

I created a single batch file that copies all my projects' apk files to the desired location.

---

Is there a way to change the output location of the bin folder to somewhere outside the project or more preferably ***run the batch file after each build***?

---

***NOTICE***

I am using eclipse with ADT. I have tried to add a builder that executes the batch file. However, when the batch file is run, the apk file is not yet generated. I tried all combinations of options in the builder and all the possible of sequences of builders.

Comment: Are you using a `Makefile`? If so, what's it look like? It'd be easy to adjust most `Makefile`s for this task, anyway...

Comment: I use the android plugin for eclipse? It is really embarrassing but I don't know about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are happy just to use Eclipse whilst you are perfecting the build, then switching to the command line for the final build, then with Ant it's really easy to get what you want with very little effort or configuration.

**Assumptions**

**1)** Your sources are in an Android workspace and you will end up with two sets of binaries - one made by Eclipse, the other made by Ant will end up outside the workspace as set by a PROPERTIES file

**2)** You are using SDK14 or 15 (Ant changed in 14)

**3)** You have Ant installed and in your path - you'll need to have Ant 1.8.2 - this is not the internal one that Eclipse uses, you may have to get it from the Apache site, it's easy to install

**Steps**

**1)** Make a sample project from the command line as described in http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html

For example I used:
android create project --target 8 --name Sample15App --path c:\dev
\projects\samples\Sample15 --activity Sample15Activity --package com.me.samplefifteen

This will make a directory and some files which you will use later as a template in your projects

**2)** Make a sample project in your workspace from Eclipse, I made EclipseSample in one of my workspaces

**3)** Copy the following files from Sample15App to the root of your EclipseSample project:

build.xml
ant.properties
local.properties

**4)** Edit ant.properties (which is initially empty) to be like this example:

```
projectname=EclipseSample
workspace.dir=/dev/projects/EclipseIndigo/AndroidWorkTwo
base.dir=${workspace.dir}/${projectname}
outbasebase.dir=/dev/projects/AntBuilds
outbase.dir=${outbasebase.dir}/${projectname}
ant.project.name=${projectname}
out.dir=${outbase.dir}/bin
layout.dir=${base.dir}/res/layout
source.dir=${base.dir}/src
```

From this you can see that my workspace is **/dev/projects/EclipseIndigo/AndroidWorkTwo**

The eclipse project under this is in directory **EclipseSample**

I want my apks to end up in **/dev/projects/AntBuilds/EclipseSample** (i.e outbasebase concatenated with projectname -so for other projects you can use a very similar ant.properties file just change projectname)

**5) IMPORTANT - EDIT THE build.xml**

Comment out or remove the line :

```
<project name="Sample15App" default="help">
```

replace it with just

```
<project>
```

This just means it will pick up the project name from ant.properties rather than the build.xml and you can use the same build.xml in all your projects, only ant.properties need change

**6)** try it with **"ant debug"** should build the debug apks under /dev/projects/AntBuilds/EclipseSample

**7)** finally if you want to automate the release build (signing and password entering automatically) add lines like

```
key.store.password=YourPassword
key.alias.password=YourPassword
key.store=c:/users/you/yourrelease-key.keystore
key.alias=release_alias
```

to the ant.properties and then you just type **"ant release"**

If you don't add them it will tell you to sign manually and as no password entries were found in 'build.properties' (- that was what ant.properties used to be called pre SDK 14, they should have corrected this!)

Answer (score 4):

You can add new Builders to your project using `Project Properties->Builders->New...`.

One way to do this is to create an ant build (which copies the file), or just a plain old script or batch file.

Comment: How can I make the batch file run AFTER the build is done? precisely after the apk file in `bin folder` is created

Comment: You can move the builders up and down using the Up and Down buttons on the Builders page. If you want it to happen after the build, move it down after the all of the other builders.

Comment: Please bare with me. I added a new builder. Set the `Location` to the batch file location. Now, in `Build Options`, there is the option called "Run the builder:" where I should choose one of the checkboxes at least: (After a clean) - (During manual builds) - (During auto builds) - (During a clean). None of them is working for me and the batch file is giving an error that the file is not found so it is trying to copy before the creation of the file. One more thing, it seems the file is executed only when "After a clean" is checked.

Comment: I've just created a new builder in a project which runs a batch file, and it's working for me (with auto-build). Have you attached the builder to one project, but are changing another? Or are your paths incorrect?

Comment: No No it is not working! try to use a batch file that copies the apk from bin directory to somewhere else. It will throw an error about the file being not found.

Comment: go to chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5133/run-batch-file-after-each-build-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks @MatthewFarwell. The 'builders' approach is vastly simpler that all the messing about with ANT etc in other answers I've found to this question (just running a SH file after/during a build).